# How to create custom page in Wordpress with new stylesheet?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

New to wordpress so struggling a little bit here.

Basically I've got 4 custom page templates that I need to create: Home, Portfolio, About, Contact.

For each of these new pages I need a new CSS file. I've enqueued my script `portfolio.css` as such:

```
function my_custom_styles() {

wp_register_style( 'portfolio', 
get_template_directory_uri().'/portfolio.css' );

if ( is_portfolio ) {

wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_styles' );
```

This works great - my only problem is that my main stylesheet `style.css` is clashing with this and overwriting a lot of the styles. Basically both `style.css` and `portfolio.css` are loading at the same time.

How do I get it so that only style.css loads on my Homepage, `portfolio.css` loads on my Portfolio page, `about.css` only loads on my about page etc.

I can't seem to find any help online for this!

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, `portfolio.css`, `about.css`, etc. would **extend** `style.css`, where most of the core styles (font size, weight, padding, accent declarations, etc.) would be defined in `style`, but `portfolio` would add some additional styles not used elsewhere.

If you truly want them to be mutually exclusive, you'll have to dequeue the style.css file.

View your page source and search for `/YOURACTIVETHEME/style.css`. Note the `id="some-style-id"` in the `<link>` tag. That's the "handle" for the stylesheet, and you can use [`wp_deregister_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) or [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) to remove it.

Also, clean up your code, it's going to get hard to maintain with those inconsistent indentations. Going through your code, are you sure your `if` statement is working? `is_portfolio` is being as a constant right now… You're probably intending it to be passed using something like the [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) or [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) functions.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_styles' );
function my_custom_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'portfolio', get_template_directory_uri().'/portfolio.css' );

    if( is_page('portfolio') ){ // Use Page Title, Page Slug, or Page ID here
        wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'YOUR-ID-FROM-EARLIER' );
    }
}
```

All of this said, if you have custom page templates, you could just use put

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio', get_template_directory_uri().'/portfolio.css' );
wp_dequeue_style( 'YOUR-ID-FROM-EARLIER' );
```

in the page template files.

Another thing to consider is that you're using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) which will pull from the parent theme. If you want the active child theme that uses a template (ala [Genesis](https://www.studiopress.com/features/)) you'll need to use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) instead.

Comment: Everything you said makes perfect sense. I think having all main styles in style.css and then having additional styles that aren't used elsewhere in portfolio.css is best practice and the cleanest way to go about things. Also thanks for correcting the code I was putting into my functions.php - I've had a play since you're answer and everything is working great now.